# UTF-8 characters in a path to a jarfile

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, jar, console

I have a folder with Unicode(UTF-8) symbols in its name, for example, ***Я_Папка***, and the folder contains **foo.jar**.

Now I need to execute the foo.jar:

```
chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>java -Dsun.jnu.encode=UTF-8 -jar C:\Я_Папка\foo.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Я_Папка\foo.jar
```

**-Dsun.jnu.encode=UTF-8** switch tells java to use UTF-8 encoding for the platform string.

**-Dfile.encode=UTF-8** switch can't help - it works only with the contents of files rather than the command line

My question here - how to make **-jar** switch understand UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: What happens with no `-D` option in default code page?

Comment: Default code page is Cp1252 and is too old to understand UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @vlshch what specific windows version are you using? `chcp 65001` and `java -jar` work fine on windows 7, though you might need to change default cmd font. seems like the issue is relevant to win 10 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't support Unicode (UTF-8) for platform string on Windows by design. You can only use code page set in the System locale.

Comment: what do you mean by "code page set in the System locale"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on Russian locale you should probably change "system locale" setting. I've had same problem, see the [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40520549/error-unable-to-access-jarfile-encoding-issue).