# Error: Unable to access jarfile. Encoding issue

Tags: java, windows, jar, windows-10

The problem seems trivial, but could not find a solution so far.

```
C:\Users\User>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -jar "D:\Valya\Учёба\ТРПК\наумов_трпк_лаб2\build\libs\naumov_trpk_lab2-runnable.jar"
Error: Unable to access jarfile D:\Valya\?????\????\??????_????_???2\build\libs\naumov_trpk_lab2-runnable.jar
```

The issue appears only when I try to access a jar that is sitting in a dir with non-ASCII name. I am 100% sure I could run jars with such a path when I was on Windows 7, but since I moved to Win 10, no luck. Quoting the path does not help, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` also.

BTW, if I run app from Intellij IDEA clicking on the main method, I get the following error.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Valya\Учёба\тест-кириллицы\out\production\тест-кириллицы;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)
```

My java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)
```

Feel free to ask for *any* additional info, cause I have just no clue.

**UPD**
The original version of Windows, on which I had the issue is Win 10 LTSB installed with English (US) locale. But with the Russian locale installed from scratch on VM the problem is gone. And output is:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents>java -jar наумов_тпрк_лаб2.jar
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile эрєьют_ЄяЁъ_ырс2.jar
```

Yes, corrupt because it's plaintext, but path is found, no original error. Don't let the letters fool you, that was not a chcp problem: although original codepage is 866, any other let java find path to the file.

Comment: Did u tried putting the quotes around the complete path ? CMD can read the non-ascii paths but cannot displays that.

Comment: @umais-gillani yes, i did. fixed the answer, so it was clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` has nothing to do with filenames, but has something with [filecontents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).

And the sweet part.

1. Open start menu, type to find "Region & language settings".
2. Go to Related settings.
   [image: Related settings.]
3. Then click on Change location...
   [image: Change location...]
4. And set the proper country
   [image: And set the proper country]

So, it finally works, but I hope someone provides details on this.